# Omniauth Facebook logging in not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku

I've been trying to create a user authentication system for my latest project. I've decided not to store any password and stuff and use social networks to allow people use specific functions in my projects (post articles, etc).

I've just finished a tutorial by Sergio Tapia Gutierrez on https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw. As it seems in the comments, the tutorial steps are correct for most of the users. But not for me.

I've done everything the same way he mentioned on his post yet I'm facing quite a few bugs right now.

Firstly, it's the recognition script. My rails app seems not to recognize whether user is logged in or not though I've put every line of code in my app as mentioned in tutorial. 
Strangely, when I click multiple times, it starts to recognize and logs me in.

The next thing that bugs me a lot is javascript. I host my app on Heroku - sometimes JS seems not to be reacting to mouse clicks (jquery actually). I've also put a pop up script for Facebook dialog - it does not pop up either.

I'm sorry I cannot explain it properly - I'm new on Rails and I'm quite lost at the moment - I have no idea where the real problem is, these are just the guesses.

Facebook.js.coffee

```
    jQuery ->
      $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

      $.ajax
        url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
        dataType: 'script'
        cache: true


    window.fbAsyncInit = ->
      FB.init(appId: 'MyAppId(i've put it here, can't show ya :)', cookie: true)

      $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        FB.login (response) ->
          window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse

      $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
        FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
          FB.logout() if response.authResponse
        true
```

A block of code from application.html.erb

```
<div id="user-widget">
  <% if current_user %> 
    Welcome <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>!
    <%= link_to "Sign out", "#", id: "sign_out" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "#", id: "sign_in" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And user status checker from application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

Lastly, the sessions controller code

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to articles_path, :notice => "Logged in"
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to articles_path, :notice => "Logged out"
  end
end
```

**Update!** I've checked the JS console. It keeps spitting out this line - "FB.login() called when user is already connected." What does it mean? It does not seem the user is connected, but it keeps popping out that.

Comment: So, to be a little more clear, you are not always able to click and log in, and javascript seems to be flakey?

Comment: Yes. When I run my app localy, it seems to be working perfectly - if I click on sign in/ out div, a window pops out as it should. When on Heroku, it's not that it doesn't read my clicks - the console shows some activity, but nothing happens, just the redirect, invoked by the rails code.

Comment: Where's your controller code for creating the session with your app? It's not enough to login to Facebook. Your `/auth/facebook/callback` action should get an authentication token back from which you can create a session in your app. I don't see your sessions controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work on production, You have to make some changes in facebook app settings

1. Your app domain should be  **herokuapp.com**
2. Site url  **http://yourappname.herokuapp.com/**
3. and Should not be in sandbox mode

Comment: Thanks for your tips, but that doesn't help either - I've completed these steps even before. No luck at all - seems as if the app does not want recognize anyone.

Comment: Which `omniauth-facebook` version are you using? For me it works with 1.4.0 as in the example, but does not work with 1.5.0, 1.6.0.rc1